# Running dplyr, grepl in MySQL

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr, grepl

I have a table in SQL that I'm testing out `dplyr`.
I have two inputs a date range and a text field which is a company

I run the following R code below

```
  # Filter on the Customer and the date range the user selects
  mydf <- db %>%
    tbl(table) %>%
    filter(TableDate >= start_date & TableDate <= end_date) %>% 
    filter(grepl('company', company_name)) %>% 
    collect()
```

So in theory this should select information from a single table between `start_date` and `end_date` for the company `company` [like a fuzzy match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999491/filtering-observations-in-dplyr-in-combination-with-grepl) as the company names contain things like X industries and Y incorporated

I get an error like follows

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
>     could not run statement: execute command denied to user 'shiny'@'%' for routine 'mydb.GREPL'

when i have a look at the sql

```
myDF <- tbl(db,table)
myDF1 <- filter(myDF, TableDate >= start_date & TableDate <= end_date)
myDF2 <- filter(myDF1, grepl('company', company_name))

explain(myDF2)
```

I get the output

```
<SQL>
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE (`TableDate ` >= '2015-01-01' AND `TableDate ` <= '2015-06-01')) `lpknlorhcn`
WHERE (GREPL('company', `company_name`))
```

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
>     could not run statement: execute command denied to user 'shiny'@'%' for routine 'mydb.GREPL'

I have modified the code and output slightly for privacy reasons

### Questions

- Does anyone know how to set this up correctly (I know its a permissions thing on the mysql side but im not sure where as the user shiny has execute access
- Why does the SQL in the explain plan look so funny (it has two where clauses for instance) and what is `lpknlorhcn`

Thank you kindly for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support `grepl()`. You can either use `%like%` or collect the data first, then use `grepl()`.

See [this question about using grepl in dply/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329851/ifelse-grepl-commands-when-using-dplyr-for-sql-in-db-operations/33633602#33633602) for more info and examples.